# IOS Chat application using XMPP Protocol (ejabberd) Room chat issue

Tags: chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

> I am developing an IOS Chat application using XMPP Protocol(ejabberd).  My chat room is created at my server, it return roomID to me.

I am facing an issue in room/group chat. When i am sending a single message it is repeating more than once like 3 to 4 times.How to fix this. My code is here

```
 XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[roomDict objectForKey:KEY_group_id]];

XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomCoreDataStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom activate:[ChatHandler sharedInstance].xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self
        delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[self insertRoomObjectWithDictionary:roomDict];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[[ChatHandler sharedInstance] xmppStream].myJID.user
                        history:nil
                       password:@""];
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
return xmppRoom;
```

[image]

Comment: if it is repeating in your iOS chat view or on server. And when you create the room how many user you added to that group.

Comment: @GaganJoshi I have fixed this problem. before inserting messages in core db i am comparing there local time stamp if they are same then return other wise insert.

Comment: @alok srivastava: Please add your solution by code as an answer to the question.

Comment: @aloksrivastava hi , i need to develop single and multichat functionality in iOS (using Swift) , can you share few links which helps me what are the main things which need to handle in such application?

Comment: @aloksrivastava hey i need to configure Ejabberd on Amazon any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet worked for me.. Try it for your code...
I have sent uuid of my device as child while sending message and checked the same uuid at the time of incoming message :

```
-(void)sendMessageWithBody:(NSString *)messageBody
{
    if ([messageBody length] == 0) return;

    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body" stringValue:messageBody];

    XMPPMessage *message = [XMPPMessage message];
    [message addChild:body];

    NSString *uuidString=[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;

    NSXMLElement *myMsgLogic=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"myMsgLogic" stringValue:uuidString];
    [message addChild:myMsgLogic];

    [self sendMessage:message];
}

-(void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message fromOccupant:(XMPPJID *)occupantJID;
{
    [self handleIncomingMessage:message room:xmppRoom];
}

-(void)handleIncomingMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message room:(XMPPRoom *)room
{
    NSString *uuidString=[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;

    NSString *messageLogic= [[message elementsForName:@"myMsgLogic"].firstObject stringValue];

    if ([uuidString isEqualToString:messageLogic]) {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"handleIncomingMessage" message:[message body] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same chat application using xmpp ejabbered. I was also facing the same problem. In my case on xmpp server they have set offline message storage to 100. If in offline mode the message limit crossed 100 then from 101th message I will get bounce back that message. So as a solution we changed the offline message limit to 500.

```
{mod_offline_odbc, [
 {user_max_messages, 500}
]}
```